# embedded glassfish: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/ServiceLoader

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-embedded

I am trying to embed glassfish inside my java program using embeded api, I am using maven2 and its pom.xml is as follows

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>orh.highmark</groupId>
  <artifactId>glassfish-test1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>glassfish-test1</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
<repository>
<id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
<name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
<url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
<layout>default</layout>
</repository>
        <repository>
            <id>glassfish-repository</id>
            <name>GlassFish Nexus Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish</url>
        </repository>

  </repositories>
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>

            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>orh.highmark.App</mainClass>
          <arguments>
            <argument>argument1</argument>

          </arguments>

        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Program:

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    Server.Builder builder = new Server.Builder("test");
    builder.logger(true);
    Server server = builder.build();
    }
}
```

But for some reason it always gives me error as  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/ServiceLoader`

here is the output

```
C:\Users\sunils\glassfish-tests\glassfish-test1>mvn -e exec:java
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building glassfish-test1
[INFO]    task-segment: [exec:java]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Preparing exec:java
[INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
[INFO] [exec:java {execution: default-cli}]
Hello World!
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] An exception occured while executing the Java class. null

java/util/ServiceLoader
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: An exception occured whi
le executing the Java class. null
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(Defa
ultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandalone
Goal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(Defau
ltLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHan
dleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegmen
ts(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLi
fecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:6
0)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)

        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured
while executing the Java class. null
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPlugi
nManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(Defa
ultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:290)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/ServiceLoader
        at org.glassfish.api.embedded.Server.getMain(Server.java:701)
        at org.glassfish.api.embedded.Server.<init>(Server.java:290)
        at org.glassfish.api.embedded.Server.<init>(Server.java:75)
        at org.glassfish.api.embedded.Server$Builder.build(Server.java:185)
        at org.glassfish.api.embedded.Server$Builder.build(Server.java:167)
        at orh.highmark.App.main(App.java:14)
        ... 6 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Sat May 08 02:55:03 IST 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/6M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I couldn't guess its problem with my program or with the glassfish api. Can somebody please help me understand what is happening here and how to rectify it?

thanks for any clue ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is gone after I installed new version of jdk :)